# Which Browser(s) support auto-update version?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, browser, safari

I am building/deploying apps. But I need to plan about the future. So, I need to know which browsers currently support auto-update version?

Comment: [firefox](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/update-firefox-latest-version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature was firstly introduced by [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/), than gradually adapted by [Firefox](http://firefox.com).

Update: 
This feature is now available in IE10.

Comment: [IE10 Can auto update too](http://i.imgur.com/l4HGB.png).

Answer (score 0):

`Google Chrome` and `Firefox` have implemented it. IE is planning to implement it.

Just go through this [link](http://www.webmonkey.com/2011/12/microsofts-new-automatic-update-plan-could-mean-the-end-of-ie-6/)

Comment: As @Nacereddine pointed out, IE10 auto-updates.

Comment: @JonathanSampson:- Exactly!! :)